# Error in my AVR BUTTON code

Tags: microcontroller, avr, gpio, button

Can anyone help me understand whats wrong in my logic for writing a push button that toggles a LED in this way? I know the XOR way, I just want to figure out why it doesn't work when written in this form.

Here is the code:

```
#include <avr/io.h>

#define LED 5
#define BUTTON 0

int main(void)
{
    DDRD |= (1<<LED);
    DDRD &= ~(1<<BUTTON);

    unsigned char flag = 0;

    while(1)
    {
        if(PIND & (1<<BUTTON) && flag == 0)
        {
            PORTD |= (1<<LED);
            flag = 1;
        }

        if(PIND & (1<<BUTTON) && flag == 1)
        {
            PORTD &= ~(1<<LED);
            flag = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Now the code works just fine after adding the delay but could you explain why i need it (delay) when toggling led with this way but not when toggling using the XOR method?
Here is the code for the xor method :

```
#define F_CPU 8000000Ul
#include <avr/io.h>
#define led 5
#define pb 0

int main(void)
{
    DDRD|= 1<<led;
    PORTD &= ~(1<<led);
    unsigned char press=0;

    while(1)
    {
        //TODO:: Please write your application code
        if(PIND&(1<<pb))
        {
            if (press == 0 )
            {
                PORTD ^= (1<<led);        //toggling the led
                press =1;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            press = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please insert the code, and the relevant part of the schematic, in your post.  Your screenshot did not appear in your question.

Comment: Circuit diagram? What happens when you push the button?

Comment: Next time copy pase your code into the question, select it and hit`{}` on the toolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code may be toggling the LED just how you intended.  However, it may be toggling the LED so fast that you cannot see it.  It takes a bit of time for your eye to perceive that the LED is off.  And if the LED is turned on again too soon then your eye will perceive the LED as being on, or a bit dim, rather than switching on and off.

Try adding some delay (100 ms or more) after each time the LED is turned on and off.

Comment: Adding the delay worked , Could you check my question again as i have edited it?

Comment: @Ahmed The XOR code example does not toggle the LED in the same way.  The XOR code requires you to release the button and press the button again to toggle the LED.  But your original example toggles the LED while you're holding the button down.  The XOR code will toggle only as fast as you can re-press the button, which is relatively slow.

Answer (score 1):

You code is fine regarding the Data Direction Registers, you set the GPIO directions correctly.

If you set a bit (to 1) in the Data Direction Resgister, the corresponding pin will be output. If you clear it (to 0) it will be an input.

Your problem seems to be with your hardware, lack of knowledge of your hardware. A push button can be active low or active high.

[image]

1. In the first case, the button is active low. So when you push it the pin will read 0, as it will be connected to GND. When it is not pushed it will read 1 as the pin is pulled up to VCC by a resistor.

   In this case your code won't work because it checks if the pin is 1, which won't be if the button is pushed.

   ```
   if(PIND & (1<<BUTTON) && flag == 0)
   ```

   Probably this is your button's configuration so you should check if it is 0.

   ```
   if(!(PIND & (1<<BUTTON)) && flag == 0)  // note the '!' operator
   ```
2. In the second case, the button is active high. When pushed the pin will read 1, as it will be tied to VCC. If unpushed it will read 0 because of the pull-down resistor to GND. In this case your code should work.